# IE8 $.map not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

IE8 doesn't support javascript's map function, so I'm using jQuery's:

```
jQuery.map( Ids, function( Id ) {}
```

However, the above function results in this error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I've also tried

```
$.map( Ids, function( Id ) {}
```

But that gets the same error. `Ids` is an array of short strings. Any ideas why this is happening?

**Update:**
Here's my version:

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.0
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2014-01-23T21:02Z
 */
```

Comment: Is it just a typo that you are missing the closing paren `)` on those two map function calls?

Comment: jQuery version? is it a 2.x version?

Comment: jQuery 2.x requires IE9+. If you absolutely need IE8, use jQuery 1.x. If you don't, let IE8 die. http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @Amadan jQuery 1.11 is the current version supported in IE8?

Comment: @anderssonola all 1.x branch versions still support IE8

Comment: @anderssonola: edited to be more precise.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm running 1.11